# Obtaining all sub list of list with element in the same order with Python

Tags: python, list

my problem is the following:

for a given list of length L
for example (L=4):

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

i would like to obtain all the possible "sublist" of lenght X of this list while keeping the order of the elements.
for X=2 it would return me:

```
["a","b"]
["a","c"]
["a","d"]
["b","c"]
["b","d"]
["c","d"]
```

I don't really know how to start, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for the task:

```py
from itertools import combinations

lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
X = 2

for c in combinations(lst, X):
    print(list(c))
```

Prints:

```py
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'd']
['b', 'c']
['b', 'd']
['c', 'd']
```